# How do I correctly access WSDL for SOAP connection?

Tags: magento-1.9, api, soap, wsdl

When running this, I only get an "HTTP ERROR 500" page. As I've seen in other solutions I've added the 'index.php' before the /api section. I've also enabled WSI-Compliance mode as I've seen suggested.

```
<?php
    $proxy = new SoapClient('http://stagingsite.club/index.php/api/v2_soap/?wsdl');
    $sessionId = $proxy->login('inventory', 'password');

    $result = $proxy->catalogCategoryTree($sessionId);
    var_dump($result);
?>
```

This is how Magento documentation lists the path

```
$proxy = new SoapClient('http://magentohost/api/v2_soap/?wsdl');
```

I'd like to point out that on my web server, I do not have a similar path. I'm confused in that I don't completely understand the concept of WSDL. Is the WSDL file created, or is it an actual file that I need to find in my directory? I've ensured that SOAP is enabled.

[image: Directory Tree]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Hey I'm using the SOAP api in one of our products and the url I use to get the wsdl is example.com/api/v2_soap?wsdl=1.

I was pretty new to SOAP api when I started using Magento's so I share some of the stuff I learned:

- the wsdl is kinda like a sitemap for all the methods and parameters that the service offers hence the name 'Web Services Description Language'
- It is not something that you need to create. Since the SOAP functionality is packaged with Magento, so is it's wsdl
- Download a tool to help you work with SOAP api's. I personally use [SoapUI](https://www.soapui.org/downloads/latest-release.html). It will let you enter the url path to the wsdl and will create example requests for each method showing the optional and required params. This helped me a lot when starting with SOAP api's.

Let me know if you have any more questions